# font awesome spinner not animating in rails app deployed using passenger but works in local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, font-awesome

I am using

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```

for creating a spinner icon in my rails app. It works fine in my local server but when I deploy it on aws ec2 instance the icon doesn't animate.Since it is working fine in the local machine I am guessing there has to be something wrong with the rails config in ec2. Can anyone please help?

P.S : I am using passenger for deploying my rails app and it is running in development mode.

Comment: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/74

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @user273895 This issue is still persisting when I deploy the app on the server.

Comment: I had a similar issue, the spinner worked on my local but not on the deployed environments (we're not using EC2 or passenger).
What fixed my issue was just upgrading the font-awesome-sass gem to the latest version (4.6.2).

Comment: @user273895... I used the latest font-awesome-sass gem and it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

First, check in your browser console if you get all the assets:  css, javascript, etc. (status code shouldn't be 404).

Second, under Passenger Rails runs production by default. Are you sure you run in development mode? If not, that could explain the problem, as the assets won't be compiled.

If so, try compiling the assets:

```
rake assets:precompile
rake assets:clean
```

Third, and this an advice: once your application is deployed somewhere, anywhere, run in production mode. If you have to know on which environment you are running, add a new environment variable, say `APP_ENV`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Eric. I checked in my browser and status code isn't zero. I am running my app in development mode so that I can get logs and debug bugs. I will put it into production mode as soon as all the app is finished. The font awesome spinner is still not spinning. It works fine in my local machine but appears static when I deploy it. Any ideas?